# not able to reverse operation. The error that says it cannot convert void to string but my result is saved as string. Have shown the code to refer

Tags: c++, c++14, cppcheck

```
string result;
for(int i=st.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
 result+=st.top();
 cout<<st.top()<<endl;
 st.pop();}
 result+='\0';
 return reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
```

st is a stack of character. I want to output stack elements in reverse order

Comment: Please post [mcve] and exact error message.

Comment: `reverse()` is an in-place transformation.

Comment: Did you look at the return type of [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `std::reverse()` is `void`, so you can't `return` it (except from a function that itself returns `void`).

`std:reverse()` modifies the contents of the input range inline, so just `return` the `std::string` variable whose characters you are asking `std::reverse()` to modify, eg:

```cpp
string result;
while (!st.empty()){
    result += st.top();
    cout << st.top() << endl;
    st.pop();
}
reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
return result; // <-- here
```

Alternatively, you could just use `string::insert()` instead and not use `std::reverse()` at all, eg:

```cpp
string result;
result.reserve(st.size());
while (!st.empty()){
    result.insert(0, st.top());
    cout << st.top() << endl;
    st.pop();
}
return result;
```